# JSON object with binary values from salesforce

Tags: python, json, salesforce

I am downloading data from salesforce using simple_salesforce package in Python.

```
sf = Salesforce(username='xxx', password='xxx', security_token='xxx')

query_res = sf.query_all('select variable from table')
```

The downloaded JSON object has binary/garbage values. `example - "�.�>����$"`.

This problem happens only when I download data from server. If I run the same code in local system then I get correct results.

Any idea how can I resolve the problem?

Thanks